# formatting label on a mouse hover of donought in React chartJS

Tags: css, reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs

I am new  to Chart.JS, I am trying to use the 'Donought' Chart in my project, Which looks kind of like the following:

https://github.com/jerairrest/react-chartjs-2/blob/master/example/src/components/doughnut.js

In this example, When you hover on any of the data sets, You get a related label for that data set, However,When you get that label and hover on it, How good you are able to show it is my question... 
 [image]

Instead, What it should look like is:
[image]

In the Above example, I cannot read the entire label 'Health Relationship' as i read the 'StaffOf' with a square prepended to it.

I completely understand that 'StaffOf' has got lesser number of letters where as 'Health Relationship' has more letters.

Is there a way in ReactJS or ChartJS where we can justify the label to look completely as in (Able to read the word completely by using some kind of a word wrap, which in this case is not working at all) without modifying the size of the donought using CSS?

Any Help would be appreciated..